# Which topics can i use to receive all turtlebot sensors information?

Tags: navigation, odometry, turtlebot2, turtlebot, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i already have the turtlebot 2, and i want to subscribe all topics that have any information from sensors. I already subscribe the odom topic and cmd_vel topic, and i want to know which topics are lacking

---

```
void odomCallback(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& odom)
{
ROS_INFO("I received odom: [%f,%f,%f]", odom->pose.pose.position.x, odom->pose.pose.position.y,odom->pose.pose.position.z);
}

ros::Subscriber sub_odom = nh.subscribe("odom", 1000, odomCallback);
```

---

This code is right? Where can i see more subscribers to the other sensors?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198262/which-topics-can-i-use-to-receive-all-turtlebot-sensors-information?/) by [leobber](https://answers.ros.org/users/20424/leobber/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-11-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Basically everything under `/mobile_base/sensors/` although some are redundant/processed.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0